How to strip debugging content from kotlin code using proguard?
I developed an android app using kotlin, and when I decompiled my code, in the smali file, I saw a lot of this.
/a/l.smali:61:    const-string v5, "null cannot be cast to non-null type java.lang.Class<T of kotlin.jvm.JvmClassMappingKt.<get-java>>"
/a/l.smali:135:    const-string v0, "null cannot be cast to non-null type T of androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get"
/b1/b.smali:192:    const-string v1, "null cannot be cast to non-null type android.view.WindowManager"
/c/d.smali:421:    const-string p1, "null cannot be cast to non-null type T of androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get"
/d1/m.smali:53:    const-string v2, "null cannot be cast to non-null type android.content.ClipboardManager"
/d1/o.smali:135:    const-string v4, "null cannot be cast to non-null type cn.lalaki.desk.m.AppDetails"
/d2/e.smali:495:    const-string v3, "null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.Array<kotlin.Any?>"


I understand all this due to my use of forced transformations.
kotlin automatically generates many of these strings.
These error logs are thrown when a program error occurs.
But for the production environment, I don't need these strings, is there any way to replace them with empty ones?
I don't have any idea right now, maybe I can change the code and try not to use "as" for type conversion, but use "if ... is Type"...
But there are a lot of codes like this that can only be used as an alternative, so if anyone has experience with this, I hope they can come to my aid. Thanks!
